# UFT / QTP : unable to access Object.CurrentStyle in Firefox

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am using the below code for fetching the font size of a "link" on **IE**.

```
Browser("BB").Page("PP").Link("link").Object.CurrentStyle.fontSize
```

However, if I use the same code on **FireFox**, QTP/UFT throws error:

> object required "Object.CurrentStyle".

After alot of research and exploration I found that for FireFox it is not `Object.CurrentStyle`, but it is `Object.Style` which is an inbuilt function in QTP, and used below code

```
Browser("BB").Page("PP").Link("link").Object.style.fontSize
```

but I'm not fetching the results for the firefox

Comment: Once you dig down to Object you are out side of UFT functionality and interacting with the underling object - the available functionality is dependant on the developer. For Browser independence I would select the node from the DOM and extract the attributes.

Comment: could you please explain with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`TestObject.Object.currentStyle.fontSize`
```

*will work only on IE not on FireFox*, we may get the option to use "Style" in place of "currentStyle" for FireFox but that doesn't work properly. Also the **FontSize is read as "FontSize" in IE** and **"font-size" in Firefox**

To retrieve the required information form the application on **Firefox**

```
set FXObj= Browser("title:=Test_2").Page("title:=Test_2").Link("text:=link")

Set webElem = FXObj.Object
Set compStyle=Browser("title:=Test_2").Page("title:=Test_2").Object.defaultView.getComputedStyle(webElem, "")

fntsize = CompStyle.getPropertyValue("font-size")
Print fntsize
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when switching between browsers. IE has a special style object that is not supported in other browsers. I suggest a more generic tactic, treat style for what it is - an html attribute. You could go pure DOM, but lets use the UFT test objects:

Step 1: find the html node you want to extract style from:
`Set element = Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=HelloWorld").WebElement("xpath:=//html/body/div[@id='something']")`

Step 2: extract the style data
`attributeValue = element.Object.GetAttribute("style")`

attributeValue is now a string containing the style attribute data, it can be split, RegExp'd or what ever you need

Comment: I'm facing issue on a **Object.CurrentStyle** on Firefox.
Its not about identifying the object. however i tried the method which you expliend but facing same issue.


`set FXObj= Browser("application version:=Mozilla Firefox 34\.0\.5","title:=Test_2").Page("title:=Test_2").Link("xpath:=//html/body/div[2]/div/a")`

if i use `fxmsg=FXObj.Object.Object.CurrentStyle.TextDecoration` i get error as **Object required: 'Object.CurrentStyle'**


if i use `fxmsg=FXObj.Object.Object.Style.TextDecoration` nothing is returned

Comment: There is no such thing as [currentStyle on FireFox](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html), it is IE only. That link is crazy old by [really](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is ms only

Comment: you are right, there is no currentStyle on FireFox, but it is [Style](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/style.html#style), however i was getting null value when i used style on fireFox.

Answer (score 0):

The FireFox DOM does not support all of the same methods as IE. I've solved similar problems of cross-platform testing by getting the "application version" property of the browser and using a function to determine the values I'm looking for based on the browser type.

It's not glamorous but it's saved a lot of heads for my team.

You can find the FireFox page/document DOM [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document).